Why the output of my project that uses docker build to publish a custom image of Debian, is different when ran locally vs Github actions?
I have a small project that takes the latest minimal snapshot of Debian from debian.org and after applying a sequence of dockerfile & shell scripts, outputs a gzip image. This gzip can directly be written on a disk using rufus or similar tool and it will be ready to boot on any compatible hardware.
But, I am facing a weird issue. When run locally in Git Bash, the output image works fine, but when run on GitHub using actions, the final image fails to boot up. It gives the following error on boot:
Boot-error-GitHub-Actions-image
Please help me understand what could be different in local GitBash vs GitHub Actions project execution.
I expected the output gzip image to be same when generated on GitHub actions execution vs local GitBash execution.
Here is my build flow on GitHub:
-> build.sh (*uses a dockerfile & calls methods from buildhelper.sh*)
-> buildhelper.sh (*It has all the methods like docker build*)
-> squash-me.sh (*It has methods to configure the root partition of OS*)

The above complete flow runs on GitHub actions. However, on local Git bash, I directly call build.sh. The kind of error that is coming on the boot screen, it seems like something weird is happening while calling squash-me.sh on GitHub actions, because of that, the root partition fails to load during boot.

Git Bash? Windows? You missed too many details in the question.

Yes, GitBash on windows. Thanks.
Please let me know if any more info is required.

Please delete this question and get started from the scratch. You need a true Linux machine to test locally, not Git Bash which is far from enough.

I have tested this on a Linux machine (OpenSUSE) and it is working fine. Just facing the issue on GitHub actions. Seems like some part of the project is being executed differently on GitHub actions, but have been unable to narrow it down.
